# Binary Search Tree Density?

Tags: binary-search-tree

I am working on a homework assignment that deals with binary search trees and I came across a question that I do not quite understand. The question asks how density affects the time it takes to search a binary tree. I understand binary search trees and big-O notation, but we have never dealt with density before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Density of a binary search tree can be defined as the number of nodes cumulative to a level. A  perfect binary tree would have the highest density. So the question basically asks you about how the number of nodes at each level effect the searching time in the tree. Let me know if that's not clear.

Comment: Alright, that helps me. Since the search function of a binary search tree is comparing the parent to some value, it will either move on to the left or right child to then be compared against. If a bst has a higher density, the time it takes to find a specified value will increase because of the increased number of comparisons that will occur. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @kubiej2 Best case for a binary tree is when it is dense, consider what happens if your items are sorted before inserting into a tree.